# numpy fromfile and structured arrays

Tags: python, numpy, structured-array

I'm trying to use [`numpy.fromfile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) to read a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) (file header) by passing in a [user defined data-type](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).  For some reason, my structured array elements are coming back as 2-d Arrays instead of flat 1D arrays:

```
headerfmt='20i,20f,a80'
dt = np.dtype(headerfmt)
header = np.fromfile(fobj,dtype=dt,count=1)
ints,floats,chars = header['f0'][0], header['f1'][0], header['f2'][0]
#                                ^?               ^?               ^?
```

How do I modify `headerfmt` so that it will read them as flat 1D arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `count` will always be 1, just do:

```
header = np.fromfile(fobj, dtype=dt, count=1)[0]
```

You'll still be able to index by field name, though the `repr` of the array won't show the field names.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

headerfmt='20i,20f,a80'
dt = np.dtype(headerfmt)

# Note the 0-index!
x = np.zeros(1, dtype=dt)[0]

print x['f0'], x['f1'], x['f2']
ints, floats, chars = x
```

It may or may not be ideal for your purposes, but it's simple, at any rate.

Comment: Ahh, I see ... `fromfile` is giving me an array of `count` record arrays then?  And I'm essentially slicing down a different axis when I do `header['f0']`.

Comment: Yep! Or more precisely, in a structured array, _every element_ is actually a sequence. `fromfile` with `count=1` will always return a length-1 array, and in this case, the first and only element in the array is the sequence you're wanting.

Comment: Excellent.  If you keep answering all my questions, my boss just might offer you my job ... :-P